# Deleting records having a date older than 3 days, for rolling 3 day job?

Tags: sql-server-2005, datediff, sql-delete

Prior to executing a sensitive sql command I wanted to do a sanity check.

I am trying to delete records that have a [`LoadDt`] date value older than 3 days and my code is:

```
delete IntraDayStats
where DATEDIFF(dd, LoadDt, dateadd(d,-3, getdate()) ) >= 3
```

I want to schedule this as a sql job so that my `IntraDayStats` table has a rolling 3 day history. The job will run nightly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
where DATEDIFF(dd, LoadDt, dateadd(d,-3, getdate()) ) >= 3
```

is not sargable (an index won't be used), use

```
where LoadDt < getdate()- 3
```

Next time if you want to check, make the `DELETE` a `SELECT` and see what you get back

Comment: whats is sargable ? i never heard of this... i did the select but wanted to double check the logic for a rolling three days. thanks